# Ubuntu 9.10 installer doesn't recognize the hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, installation, hard-drive

I downloaded Ubuntu 9.10 x86_64 and am trying to install it on a fairly modern system with a Gigabyte GA-MA770-UD3 motherboard.  Ubuntu 9.04 installed fine and still will when I stick that disc in, but 9.10 doesn't see my hard drive (western digital 250GB).  If I boot from the disc, I can install gparted and it does recognize the drive, but when I try to start the install process from the live disc, Ubuntu again doesn't recognize the hard drive.

I checked /var/log/messages and see this:

```
Nov 12 17:28:08 ubuntu activate-dmraid: Serial ATA RAID disk(s) detected.  If this was bad, boot with 'nodmraid'.  
Nov 12 17:28:08 ubuntu activate-dmraid: Enabling dmraid support  
Nov 12 17:28:08 ubuntu activate-dmraid: ERROR: either the required RAID set not found or more options required.  
Nov 12 17:28:08 ubuntu activate-dmraid: ERROR: either the required RAID set not found or more options required.  
Nov 12 17:28:08 ubuntu activate-dmraid: ERROR: either the required RAID set not found or more options required.  
Nov 12 17:28:08 ubuntu activate-dmraid: no raid sets and with names: "nvidia_ciiajheb-0"  
Nov 12 17:28:08 ubuntu activate-dmraid: ERROR: either the required RAID set not found or more options required.
```

I checked my BIOS, SATA is enabled and is set to IDE mode, so there shouldn't be software RAID, but nonetheless, I added nodmraid to the boot line and tried again.  It still doesn't recognize the drive.  I checked /var/log/messages again and now see this:

```
Nov 12 17:49:38 ubuntu activate-dmraid: Serial ATA RAID disk(s) detected. If this was boad, boot with 'nodmraid'.  
Nov 12 17:49:38 ubuntu activate-dmraid: Enabling dmraid support  
Nov 12 17:49:38 ubuntu activate-dmraid:  WARNING: dmraid disabled by boot option  
Nov 12 17:49:38 ubuntu activate-dmraid:  WARNING: dmraid disabled by boot option
```

Any ideas on things to try?  I've tried all of the various BIOS settings for SATA.  IDE,RAID, etc.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is/was your drived plugged into one of the sata ports that can be used in the onboard raid?

Answer (score 3):

[This thread on the Ubuntu Forums](http://newyork.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8212948) appears to be relevant. The workaround discussed there is to remove the `dmraid` package before running the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it up as raid and initializing a raid volume? In general you would want to avoid software raid via that controller... perhaps delete any existing raid volume and try access without the dmraid controller, i.e nodmraid?

Comment: I haven't tried setting up raid, there's only 1 hard drive.  I did try it without dmraid, at least, I think I did.  I added nodmraid to the boot command. Is that not how you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I had such an issue when tried to install 9.10 on RAID-0. The thing I did: I installed terminal version of Ubuntu 9.04 from network, and upgraded it to 9.10. Also I made `/boot ext3`, and everything else was `ext4`. Seems like there's problem with the new brub2 + ext4 + some HDDs. Everything works fine: I'm writing this from 9.10 ;)

Try this hack until they release an update :)

Comment: I could install 9.04 and then upgrade, but being the inquisitive person that I am, I'd like to know why 9.04 recognizes my hard drive and 9.10 does not.  ext3 vs ext4 boot partitions shouldn't cause the installer to not even recognize the hard drive right?

Comment: I'm not sure. Just wanted to have a working system, and that was my way. ext4 may not be harmful for boot. Save your time, install 9.04: you're probably going to meet some grub2 bugs which are not fixable by humble users ;)

Answer (score 0):

boot into live cd, apt-get remove dmraid, and start the installer from the live-cd desktop.
Works a charm.

Comment: thanks, i'll try this the next time i get the opportunity to wipe the drive and start fresh.  i just installed 9.04 and upgraded to 9.10.

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick:

1. boot into the live CD (first option on the installer menu)
2. open a terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal)
3. enter this command: **sudo apt-get -y remove dmraid**
4. run Install Ubuntu 9.10 from the desktop icon.